# $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(\frac{1}{x}) = L$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$. Show that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(\frac{1}{x}) = L$

My thoughts:

I need to separate this in $L \in \mathbb R$, $L = \infty$ and $L = -\infty$.
Can't really get it going though

Comment: No exactly.  There are only two cases: The limit exists (and is finite) and the limit doesn't exist (either because it is one of the infinities or oscillates )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=L$, then given $\epsilon>0$, we find some $M>0$ such that whenever $x\geq M$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. For any $x\in(0,1/M)$, then $1/x>M$ and hence $|f(1/x)-L|<\epsilon$, this proves that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}f(1/x)=L$. The other direction is treated similarly.